# Change Toolbar background color programmatically does not change Toolbar Title Background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I´m trying to change the toolbar Background color programmatically by doing this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.test_color_blue)));
```

And this is the result:

before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Some how the toolbar title still has the same background color as before.

here is my toolbar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/Theme.Toolbar">
```

And here is the Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Theme.Toolbar.Title</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you applied any custom style for actionbar in styles.xml, may be some of them is conflicting.

Comment: post your layout xml please

Comment: @DavidJhons i have posted new details on the questions

Answer (score 14):

Change your code as follows:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

**Theme / Style**

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Theme.Toolbar.Title</item>
    <!-- No need for colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent here
         this should go to the AppTheme -->
</style>
```

**Result**

Before setting the new background color:

[image: picture before background color change]

and after:

[image: picture after background color change]

Comment: Where did you put colorPrimary/PrimaryDark etc i.e. where do you place your 'AppTheme'?

Also, is there any particular reason you're not setting a parent theme?

Comment: It's basically just a custom style and I don't want to inherit any attributes from an other theme thus I'm not specifying a parent theme. Regarding `colorPrimary`: That's set in the AppTheme which is used by the application / activities. By default the `Toolbar` sets the background depending on the `colorPrimary` attribute unless you don't override it with a style.

Answer (score 7):

Late, but I hope it would be helpful comment

I had this `item` in my Activity style

```
<item name="android:background">someColor</item>
```

so when I changed `toolbar` color, title and menu items didn't change background.
I just removed this `item` and now it works perfect.

I did not have time to understand the details, but I think it might be useful to someone else.

Comment: I have found that removing this does fix the toolbar. However, how can you set the background colour without breading the toolbar?

Answer (score 4):

use this to access the textview

```
public void changeToggleTitle() {
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        for(int i= 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v = mToolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if(v != null && v instanceof TextView){
                TextView t = (TextView) v;
                // Do the magic 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my `style` I changed

```
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
```

to

```
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
```

and that seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundResource(mGameEnum.getPrimeColorRes());
```