# How to change the toolbar name and put icon with tool bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have just made the app using android studio template of Navigation view. Its all working fine but I have the following two requirements

1. I want to center the toolbar title.
2. I want to put the image beside the title.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.abdulsalam.lahoreqalander.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
    <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
    <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->
```

**Problem :**

I do not know where the title string is saved, I have checked the string.xml and there is the app name and that is exactly showing on the toolbar title.

So Any suggestion where can I change the title string without changing the app name , In fact I want to change it custom and also how to put the image beside it.

> Note I am using the template made by Android studio

.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Material Design Samples");

Comment: getSupportToolBar() will help you for title and drawable

Comment: but how to set gravity

Comment: you have to create own style for toolbar set drawable instead color http://stackoverflow.com/a/29533038/3514144

Comment: and also would not it better t handle it in design way inside xml also , I wanted to know in code in java and also in xml there is no string is set for title but how comes it is taking the title from that string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement like this in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_gravity="center">

          <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

          <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4):

in you activity class do this on create

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("example");
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
```

or edit the string resourse and change the title value and icon

Comment: to edit the string resource  , I can see which string resource is set to it , as shown in code

Comment: also in java there is no way to change the gravity

Comment: check in the manifest file the activity will be accompanied with the lable

Comment: getSupportToolbar can not be found

Answer (score 1):

First of all from [the documentation](http://The%20use%20of%20application%20icon%20plus%20title%20as%20a%20standard%20layout%20is%20discouraged%20on%20API%2021%20devices%20and%20newer.):

> The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

For setting an icon through xml you could use `android:navigationIcon` inside your Toolbar.
For setting the text I would also go with the Java code approach as I could not find anything with xml in the documentation. The text would not be centered anyway.

If you want to center the text you have to modify your Toolbar. Toolbar is a view and you can put anything inside the Toolbar you want.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"         
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_content">

        // define text and icon here

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```